# listview('refresh') not working jqm 1.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

When I dynamically change the h2 content of a collapsible list in jquery mobile 1.2 the h2 tag looses it's formatting.

Calling listview('refresh') does not seem to fix it.

Any ideas?

```
<div id="mylist" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-mini="true" >
<h2>Choose...</h2>
<ul data-role="listview">
<li data-mini="true"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li data-mini="true"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li data-mini="true"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
$("#mylist li").live( 'click',function(event){

$("#mylist h2").text($(this).text());
$("#mylist").listview('refresh');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the HTML structure that jQuery Mobile creates for your collapsible widget. The HTML structure of the `<h2>` element you're attempting to update looks like this after initialization from jQuery Mobile:

```
<h2 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="a" data-mini="true">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">
            <span class="ui-btn-text">
                Choose...
                <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
            </span>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</h2>
```

So taking this HTML structure into consideration, your code should target the `.ui-btn-text` element within the `<h2>` element.

For example:

```
$(document).on('click', "#mylist li", function(event){
    $("#mylist h2 .ui-btn-text").text($(this).text());
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XDnGs/